# Cannot overwrite the direct attr in html with css

Tags: html, css

I am working on a big project to improve it as like any other existing project I have some limitation which I need to find a workaround for it though that might not be the best option. I have some texts in the database and some of them contains image tags such as

```
<img src="http://www.cbc.ca/kidscbc2/content/the_feed/_848/april_fool_848.jpg" width="20" height="8"  />
```

Now the problem is that these images have width and  height attributes which I do not need them at all and I need to use my own styling. I know there are different ways to fix such as cleaning the db text or parse the text and clean it before wrapping it to html but these are not doable for me right now based on some limitation I have. So I need to do this in a css:

just to give you a simple version of what I want here is a simple code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<style>
img {
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
  }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>

 <div style="width: 200px; height: 300px;background-color: yellow;">

    <img
src="http://www.cbc.ca/kidscbc2/content/the_feed/_848/april_fool_848.jpg"
        width="20" height="8" />

 </div>
```

As you see I even added style to img with !important to overwrite the styles.
However still the direct attr take effect. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works here - you just had some space in your image src address: (and the closing `body`  and `html` tags were missing).

```css
img {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Insert title here</title>

</head>

<body>

  <div style="width: 200px; height: 300px;background-color: yellow;">

    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/telegraph_journal/story-pictures/100141831/leadlandscape/20170303_083808_1.jpg" width="20" height="8" />

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The missing body and html end tags are more of a "this hurts to look at" issue. They're not required - the page is no less valid without them.